# trigger jquery btn 1,2,3,4 -

Tags: jquery, triggers

I'm trying to make a function in jQuery that triggers different functions on each click. (on the same button) - But max 4 different clicks.

First click: function 1
Second click: function 2
Third click: function 3
Four and last click: function 4

It's for an image rotation. (I have tried to start something)
http://pastie.textmate.org/private/uacbnix2fjovtocks5lehq

Comment: What happens on the fifth click? `toogle` should be very close to what you want. But if you don't want to mess with the jQuery source code, you can have a look at the plugin I wrote and change it (or improve it ;)) accordingly: https://github.com/fkling/jQuery-Function-Toggle-Plugin

Comment: html5? if so you can just increment the angles on canvas right?

Comment: On the fifth click I want it to go back to function 1 (rotate to "normal" view). NOT html5 :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = 1 ; 

$('#buttonid').click(function(){

   if(i == 1) {
     function1();
     i++;
   }
   else if(i == 2) {
    function2();
    i++;
   }
   else if(i == 3) {
    function3();
    i++;
   }
   else if(i == 4) {
    function4();
    i=1;
   }

});

});
```

if i understand your question correctly . this should be the answer .

Comment: @william: Don't you think that `toggle` is much easier to use? I mean, it's your time, but don't make it more complicated than it has to be...

Comment: Hi Felix, yes u r right. I'm not sure I understand the example of toggle below. And i'm a little pressed with this feature. :-/ But Thx for your help so far!

Answer (score 3):

It seems [**`.toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is what you want:

> Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks.

which you would use like:

```
$('button').toggle(func1, func2, func3, func4);
```

---

Or to give an alternative implementation:

```
var funcs = [func1, func2, func3, func4];

$('button').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    funcs[data.click_counter]();
    data.click_counter = (data.click_counter + 1) % funcs.length;
}).data('click_counter', 0);
```